# How to develop a Meteor.js application locally offline?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

Is there a way to start the meteor server environment without automatically updating the server packages every time the serve (re)starts? I want to develop offline locally... Thnx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Meteor 1.0.2, this doesn't happen on every serve restart. You can also set the `METEOR_OFFLINE_CATALOG` environment variable to something truthy (any non-empty string) when you run Meteor below 1.0.2. But it will disable the catalog at all, you will not get updates of new packages or new Meteor releases, so make sure to unset it before upgrading to 1.0.2.